# jquery validation plug-in remote function with codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm using the jquery validation plug-in. I don't have any idea how the remote function works.

So far this is my code:

functions.js

```
user: {
            required: true,
            remote: {
                url: "http://localhost/iTransaction/home/checkUser",
                type: "post",
                async: false
            }
        }
```

Controller:

```
    function checkUser(){
    return $this->itransaction_model->checkUser();
}
```

Model:

```
function checkUser(){
    $this->db->select("user");
    $query = $this->db->get("member");
    $row = $query->row();
    echo $row->user;

    if($row->user == $this->input->post("user")){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The remote is supposed to check whether the username already exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/):

> The serverside resource is called via jQuery.ajax (XMLHttpRequest) and gets a key/value pair corresponding to the name of the validated element and its value as a GET parameter. The response is evaluated as JSON and must be true for valid elements, and can be any false, undefined or null for invalid elements, using the default message; or a string, eg. "*That name is already taken, try peter123 instead*" to display as the error message.

Your controller method returns a boolean value in a way that does not makes any sense to the library and is interpreted as false. You need to return the validation result in a different way:

```php
function checkUser(){
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
    $this->output->set_header('Expires: '.date('r', time()+(86400*365)));

    $output = json_encode(
        $this->itransaction_model->checkUser() ? true : 'That username is alreay in use'
    );

    $this->output->set_output($output);
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. It didn't even run the function. I placed some pop-ups and echoes in it to check. Do you know what's wrong, sir?

Comment: Which function are you talking about? The `checkUser` method in the controller? Try checking your requests in the browser using Firebug (or a similar tool) and see if the proper URL is being called. Also, check CI routes for any overrides (just in case)